# Sign a midlet with a certificate reply from GeoTrust

Tags: java, certificate, midlet, keystore, keytool

i got a .cer file which the request for was made from some other computer.
i imported the certificate to my keystore and tried to sign the midlet using jarsign.
and got this error:
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: somealias.  somealias must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

i was able to sign it with generated key.

any ideas how to sign it with the purchased certificate?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've left the private key, that corresponds to the certificate, on that other computer. Since it's not clear, how you created the request, it's also not clear, how to retrieve the private key (or associate it with the .cer file that you've received). Probably the best idea would be to contact GeoTrust support - some CAs provide a recovery procedure or reissue certificates in such cases.